# Javax XML Transformer removing inline style of XHTML

Tags: java, ckeditor, transformer-model

I'm using javax xml Transformer to transform xhtml block which is generated by ck-editor, All inline styles are omitted.

```
// xhtml which is generated by ck-editor
String xhtmlString = "<html ><head><title></title></head><body dir="rtl"><h1><span style="color:#c0392b"><strong>Test</strong></span></h1></body></html>"

// create a StreamSource from the XHTML
StringReader reader = new StringReader(xhtmlString);
StreamSource source = new StreamSource(reader);

// Create StreamResult
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(stringWriter);

StreamSource xslSource = new StreamSource(new 
File(config.getEditorXSLPath())); 
javax.xml.transform.Transformer xhtmlTransformer = 
transformerFactory.newTransformer(xslSource);
xhtmlTransformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ISO-10646-UCS- 
2");
xhtmlTransformer.transform(source , result);

logger.debug("String Result:\n" + stringWriter.getBuffer().toString());
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
<span class="body-paragraph"></span>
<strong>Test</strong>
<span class="body-paragraph"></span>
```

Inline style is deleted : style="color:#c0392b"

Comment: Your Java code is mangled.  Please correct it.

Comment: What is in the XSL source?  Show it to us.